# Blueimp gallery implement multiple times on one page

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, gallery, blueimp

I am using Blueimp gallery to show a lightbox on a webpage.

I can show one light box on the page OK but I want to add multiple light boxes under each other for different image categories etc (i.e. - holidays, nature, black&white etc etc).

I can get the lightboxes to display OK as separate 'row' elements on the webpage.

The problem is the second (or subsequent) lightboxes when clicking on an image in them don't open the image up correctly - they just open the image in a browser with no formatting as opposed to with a gallery style as they should.

This is the code that works fine:

```
</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html#page-top">
                    <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>  <span class="light">Back</span> to Main Page
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="index.html#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="index.html#download">Images</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="index.html#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

<section class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                       <h2>Image Gallery</h2>
    <!-- The container for the list of example images -->
    <div id="links">

    <a href="images/image-1.jpg" title="">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/image-1.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="images/image-2.jpg" title="">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/image-2.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="images/image-3.jpg" title="">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/image-3.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="images/image-4.jpg" title="">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/image-4.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="images/image-5.jpg" title="">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/image-5.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="images/image-6.jpg" title="">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/image-6.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="images/image-7.jpg" title="">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/image-7.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="images/image-8.jpg" title="">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/image-8.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="images/image-9.jpg" title="">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/image-9.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="images/image-10.jpg" title="">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/image-10.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="images/image-11.jpg" title="">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/image-11.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="images/image-1.jpg" title="">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/image-1.jpg" alt="">
    </a>

    </div>

                </div>



            </div>
        </div>

</section>


    <!-- The Gallery as lightbox dialog, should be a child element of the document body -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>


    <!-- Core JavaScript Files -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Maps API Key - You will need to use your own API key to use the map feature 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCRngKslUGJTlibkQ3FkfTxj3Xss1UlZDA&sensor=false"></script>
-->
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/grayscale.js"></script>



     <!-- Custom LIGHTBOX JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/blueimp/blueimp-helper.js"></script>
<script src="js/blueimp/blueimp-gallery.js"></script>
<script src="js/blueimp/blueimp-gallery-fullscreen.js"></script>
<script src="js/blueimp/blueimp-gallery-indicator.js"></script>
<script src="js/blueimp/blueimp-gallery-video.js"></script>
<script src="js/blueimp/blueimp-gallery-vimeo.js"></script>
<script src="js/blueimp/blueimp-gallery-youtube.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
/*jslint evil: true */
/*global window, document*/
// Including jQuery via the protocol relative url above works for both http and https.
// Explicitly including jQuery via https allows running the Gallery demo as local file:
if (!window.jQuery) {
    document.write(
        '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>'
    );
}
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.js"></script>
<script src="js/demo.js"></script>
<script src="js/blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>


<script>
document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
        link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
        options = {index: link, event: event},
        links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
    blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
};
</script>


</body>
```

I just want to add another lightbox under this and I though I could just add another 'row' element and it would work. I also tried adding a gallery section again but it still does not work. It shows up on the main page OK but it does not open up the images correctly.

Hope this is clear?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can do it better, I also had this problem.

"jQuery plugin setup

The blueimp Gallery jQuery plugin registers a global click handler to open links with data-gallery attribute in the Gallery lightbox.

To use it, follow the lightbox setup guide, but replace the minified Gallery script with the jQuery plugin version and include it after including jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
```

Next, add the attribute data-gallery to your Gallery links:

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="images/banana.jpg" title="Banana" data-gallery>
        <img src="images/thumbnails/banana.jpg" alt="Banana">
    </a>
    <a href="images/apple.jpg" title="Apple" data-gallery>
        <img src="images/thumbnails/apple.jpg" alt="Apple">
    </a>
    <a href="images/orange.jpg" title="Orange" data-gallery>
    <img src="images/thumbnails/orange.jpg" alt="Orange">
    </a>
</div>
```

The onclick handler from the lightbox setup guide is not required and can be removed."

After that just add different names of galleries to `data-gallery`, for example: `data-gallery-fruits`, and it should work :D

Answer (score 2):

Well I figured it out…

This one one thing I needed to do:

https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#container-ids-and-link-grouping

You also need to create separate scripts for each gallery you would like to display. So if you have the images in a div called:

```
 <div id="color">

    <a href="images/image-1.jpg" title="" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/image-1.jpg" alt="">
    </a>Etc Etc Etc
```

You need a specific script for this gallery and then different scripts for subsequent galleries:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('color').onclick = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
        link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
        options = {index: link, event: event},
        links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
    blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
};
</script>

<script>
document.getElementById('polaroid').onclick = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
        link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
        options = {index: link, event: event},
        links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
    blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
};
</script>
```

Thats how I got it to work anyway…

Comment: Wojciech's answer is the best.

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy with jQuery!

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div><a href="1.jpg"><img src="1.jpg"></a></div>
    <div><a href="2.jpg"><img src="2.jpg"></a></div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
    <div><a href="3.jpg"><img src="3.jpg"></a></div>
    <div><a href="4.jpg"><img src="4.jpg"></a></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.gallery', function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
    link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
    options = {index: link, event: event},
    links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
    blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
});
```

Hope, it's help.

Comment: See  Wojciech's answer. The use of the provided jquery script and the data-gallery attribute is the best answer.